# How would you write this function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, typechecking

I like to write a lot of helper functions for my applications (react, typescript).  I am always conflicted on two points.  I'll provide one of my functions below, but these two points are pretty consistent across most functions I write.

1. What "type" to return?
2. Should I check the type of a parameter?

Here is one of my functions

```
interface replacementMap {
  key: string,
  value: string
} // ex [{key: '[last]', value: 'Washington'}, {key: '[first]', value: 'George'}]

type templateString = string // ex `[last], [first]`

const replaceStringsInTemplate = (m: Array<replacementMap>, t: templateString): (string | null) => {
  // Should I do checks like this?  I usually do, but is it a waste of time or is
  // there a better way to do it?
  if (typeof t !== 'string') return null
  if (!Array.isArray(m)) return null
  
  let rtn = t;

  m.forEach((v) => {
    rtn = rtn.split(v.key).join(m.value)
  }
  return rtn;
}
```

I included my questions in the comments in the code, but overall is it good practive to to do short circuit checks on the types of the parameters in my function above.  Or are they not necessary since typescript should throw errors if a consumer tries to use my function with incorrect types?

Also, what should I return if a type check fails.  It feels kinda wrong to return an empty string, hence why I returned null.

Comment: I think if you have typed parameters, you don't need to check for the type in runtime. It's fine to specify in your library documentation that if incorrect types get used, it results in undefined behaviour.
Further, you don't have to specify any return type for lambdas. Typescript is capable of infering lambda return types automatically. [disclaimer: my own opinion]

Comment: If you *do* have a type check (which, if you do want to make the extra effort, is of course not a bad thing), do not return anything. Throw a [TypeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to check at all, it is not a standard practice unless your arguments are of type any